# DELETE FROM not working on node js with oracle database

Tags: node.js, oracle

I unknowingly sent a request twice with the same insert query which led to the same record being added twice. now when I'm trying to use the delete statement it's showing 'sending request' and is not moving forward.
[image]

but the delete statement is working if I try n delete any other record with does not have duplicate values. eg-
if I try using the delete statement on the record having request 1001, it isn't working, as there are 2 records with the same request_id.
but if I try to delete the record with the request id 1002, its working.

this is my code-

```
var express=require('express');
var router=express.Router();
var oracledb=require('oracledb');

router.post('/ins-rpt',function(req,res,next){
//get the data from req
const {stat,rid,rptcomp,reqr}=req.body;
//connect with db
var connectionString="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) 
           (HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER 
           = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = orcl))"
oracledb.getConnection(
    {
        user: 'system',
        password:'Valli1234',
        tns:connectionString
    }, async function(err,con){
        if(err){
            res.status(500).json({
                message : 'not connected'
            })
        }
        else{
            //reqd opn
            var q="delete from rpt where request_id=:1";
            
            //send response
            await con.execute(q,[], 
             {autoCommit:true},function(e,s){
                    if(e){
                        res.status(500).json({
                            message : e
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.status(200).json({
                            message : s
                        })
                    }
                })
            }

        });
})

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also please verify: 1) there is an active session in the database for this client. 2) the session is executing `delete` statement or it has finished the execution. 3) it is not waiting for lock. 4) if it is waiting for lock, then verify which session and which lock is in concurrency

Comment: It looks like you are passing an empty set of bind variables when you really need to pass the request id: await con.execute(q,[] - [] seems wrong.